# how to offset 2 moving averages and change the background color whenever they cross each other?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I created an indicator of crossing over moving averages, when ema1 crosses above ema2 it is an uptrend so the background color changes to green and when the ema1 crosses below ema2 it is a downtrend and the background color changes to red but i want to be able to offset/shift the moving averages and still get the same result whenever they crossover, how do i go about it?

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Offset Emas Crossover", shorttitle="OEC", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// EMA 1
length_of_ema_1 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="Length", group="EMA 1")
source_of_ema_1 = input(close, title="Source", group="EMA 1")
offset_of_ema_1 = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500, group="EMA 1")
ema_1 = ta.ema(source_of_ema_1, length_of_ema_1)

// EMA 2
length_of_ema_2 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="Length", group="EMA 2")
source_of_ema_2 = input(close, title="Source", group="EMA 2")
offset_of_ema_2 = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500, group="EMA 2")
ema_2 = ta.ema(source_of_ema_2, length_of_ema_2)

// TREND
float color = 255
float transparency = 75
uptrend = ema_1 > ema_2
downtrend = ema_1 < ema_2

// BACKGROUND COLOR
background_color = if uptrend
    color.rgb(0, colour, 0, transparency)
else
    color.rgb(colour, 0, 0, transparency)

// PLOTTING
plot(ema_1, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset_of_ema_1)
plot(ema_2, color=color.red, title="MA", offset=offset_of_ema_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset` parameter of the `plot()` will move the line visually. It does not mean that you are checking the values with an offset.

If you want to refer to historical values (e.g. if the crossover happened two bars ago), you need to use the [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

```
uptrend = ema_1 > ema_2
downtrend = ema_1 < ema_2

// uptrend[2] -> get the value of uptrend two bars ago
// downtrend[2] -> get the value of downtrend two bars ago
```

Comment: let's say i want to offset/shift the ema1 backward by 2 and ema2 forward by 2, how do i go about it?

Comment: By shift, you do you mean shifting only the plot lines, or do you want to use previous/future values of the ema in your calculations?

Comment: using previous and future values, but i just realised that we can only shift it backward and not forward, can't access the future value. i should access the previous bars by indexing eg ema_1[1] ?

Comment: Yes, to access the previous bars, please read the link in my answer.